# Prove that second sum of Dirichlet integral in fourier series converges to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Localization in fourier series says.

At point $x_0$ behavior of fourier series of function $f$ is dependent on values of $f$ on any small neighbourhood of point $x_0$.

Proof is like this.

Pick $\delta \in (0,\pi)$ and partition Dirichlet integral into two parts.

$f(x_0-t)$ is left limit at point $x_0$
[image]

Now book uses Riemann lemma so I will write here what it says.

If $g$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ then

$lim_{\lambda \to \infty}\int_a ^b g(t)sin(\lambda t)dt=0$

Continuing proof it says that second sum of Dirichlet integral from Riemann lemma approaches $0$ when $n\to \infty$.

Can you help me understand this part?  If we want to use Riemann lemma we must show that $\frac{f(x_0-t)+f(x_0+t)}{2sin{\frac{t}{2}}}$ is integrable on $[\delta,\pi]$ yes?

Because we are writing fourier series of $f$ that means $f$ is integrable on $[-\pi,\pi]$ and has $2\pi$ period.So $f(x_0-t)+f(x_0+t)$ is bounded. $\frac{f(x_0-t)+f(x_0+t)}{2sin(\frac{t}{2})}$ is also bounded because for example $2sin(\frac{t}{2})\geq-2$ so from bounded function on segment is continuous so is also integrable. Is my thinking correct?

Comment: $f(x_{0}-t)+f(x_{0}+t)$ is a constant.

Comment: @mio I wrote that they are left and right limits. Is my argument correct at the end?

Comment: That’s correct.